# How to get length of each string in array element in swift

Tags: ios, swift

How to get length of each string in array element ["a", "a2", "b", "a2", "d"] just like "a" length is 1 and " a2" length is 2.  how to i will check length of all strings insides array in swift.

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: just loop through the array and check length. what's the complication involved?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service. Please show your efforts

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like:

```
let result = ["a", "a2", "b", "a2", "d"].map {$0.count}
// result is [1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.count` will do the work for you...

```
var strArray = ["a", "a2", "b", "a2", "d"]
strArray.forEach { (str) in
    print(str.count)
}
```

Output:

> 1
>   2
>   1
>   2
>   1

Answer (score 0):

```
// Swift 4x

for arr in array {
    print(arr.count)
}

// Swift 3x

for arr in array {
    print(arr.characters.count)
}
```

Try above solution will get all the elements counts, and I have provide a solution in both swift 3 and swift 4.

Answer (score -1):

```
var strArray = ["a", "a2", "b", "a2", "d"]
for(index, element) in strArray.enumerated()
{
    print(element.count)
}
```

//Output : 1 2 1 2 1

Comment: The solution of using a loop has already been given, and using "enumerated" here is useless (you're not using the index).